# Set namespace to XElement

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I get an empty `xmlns=""` attribute in XElemenet in an XML tree.
When I set its namespace to the document namespace, like this:

```
string xmlns="FreeForm/SchemaDescription";
XNamespace ana = xmlns;
XElement interactiveRootTag = new XElement(ana + "InteractiveRootTag");
```

the empty `xmlns=""` is not exist any more, but all of the children of this XElement, get the empty `xmlns=""`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the child element in this way:

```
string xmlns="FreeForm/SchemaDescription";

XNamespace ana = xmlns;

XElement interactiveRootTag = new XElement(ana + "InteractiveRootTag");
interactiveRootTag.Add(new XElement(ana + "ChildElement", 
    new XAttribute("attribute","AttributeValue")));
```

To get XML like this

```
<InteractiveRootTag xmlns="FreeForm/SchemaDescription">
   <ChildElement attribute="AttributeValue" />
</InteractiveRootTag>
```